# MobaXtern not asking for input when running wsl bash commands

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mobaxterm

MobaXterm not displaying all the information for a WSL command and not even asking for users input.

Following is the command I tried in powershell to open MobaXterm to run a WSL command.

```
.\MobaXterm.exe -newtab "wsl bash -c 'command here which asks user for an input'"
```

> But when I run `wsl bash -c 'command here which asks user for an input'` directly on powershell it works just fine

Please let me know how can I make MobaXterm to display all the output.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the syntax:

> For each method, you can append a command that you’d like to execute
> in the terminal. That is:
>
> - -c [command]
> - bash -c [command]
> - wsl [command] (NOTE: In this case you don’t append ‘-c’, you just type in your command)

In this case, try:

```
.\MobaXterm.exe -newtab "wsl 'command here which asks user for an input'"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I tried but result is still same. MobaXterm not showing any output regarding input.

Comment: @Goldy Can you try the other ones as well? `mobaxterm -newtab -c "echo hello"` or `mobaxterm -newtab "bash echo hello"`

Comment: Problem with these commands is that I want to initiate a wsl session first before I run my command.

Comment: @Goldy I don't have mobaxterm available to test with, but you could try with a semicolon `mobaxter -newtab "wsl; second-command"` or configure it to launch wsl by default